# Code is not changing background every half a second

Tags: processing

The title sums it up. I'm also a newbie to processing, so please, explain my error to me like I'm 5.

```
void setup(){
    size(500,500);
    int(q=1)
}

void draw(){
    if(q>0){
        float(z=random(255));
        float(x=random(255));
        float(c=random(255));
        background(z,x,c)
    }
    delay(500)
}
```

I use the browser version, if that matters.

I tried making an "if" loop, a "while" loop, I wanted it to change background color every 1/2 seconds, but instead it just changes once and then crashes. I use the browser version, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each line of code needs to be followed by a semicolon.
2. Make 'q' a global variable since you want to reference it in another function (ie draw()).  Variables defined inside a function can't be used outside of that function.
3. Remove all unnecessary parentheses.

The following code should run without errors.  Keep reading and writing code.

```
int q = 1;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  if (q > 0) {
    float z = random(255);
    float x = random(255);
    float c = random(255);
    background(z, x, c);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: OP is probably referring to `P5.js` when he states he uses the "browser version", which would explain the arbitrary lack of semicolon at times.

Comment: @laancelot Could he run it in p5.js editor without using 'function'?  I thought maybe he knew about an online editor for Processing.app which as far as I know doesn't exist.  We need more clarification on what editor he used.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Will try it out in the actual app!
https://hello.processing.org/editor/
I'm using this, and the code just crashes every time with a blank error, i'm guessing this is just a worse version of the actual processing enviroment?

Comment: I was unaware of this online editor, and you are correct the code above won't run in it for some reason (doesn't like background()).  I promise you it will run in the actual Processing4 app (either Java or Android mode), which is a free download.  We appreciate your participation here and hope that you have a rewarding coding experience.

Comment: background(z, x, c) the way that you had it also works.  I edited my answer.  Still won't run in online editor with this change.

Comment: I was likewise unaware of the Processing app being an app, and not only a browser enviroment, thank you for clarifying! And yes, it works as intended, and like a charm! And again, thank you for sharing.